# React Navigation - Pass Data on Router with navigation.navigate

Tags: react-native, parameters, router, react-navigation

I just cant seem to pass data to the selected screen using navigation.navigate. It works everywhere else but here in the Header

```
// Router.js
const ResultStack = StackNavigator({
  Result: {
    screen: Result,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
     headerTintColor: "#FFF",
     headerLeft: (<Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)} />),
     headerRight: (<Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Lab', { someKey: SomeValue }) } />),
    }),
  ...
  }
})
```

Ideally i wanted to pass on the views state on navigation.state.params to the next screen so it should look some like  `headerRight: ( navigation.navigate('Lab', navigation.state.params} />)` but it does not work.

Is this possible? or do I have to use Redux for this (which seems overkill).

**EDIT**

It seems this method does not work when trying to pass data to another stack.

Im using the setup by Spencer Carl  - [Getting Started React Navigation](https://github.com/spencercarli/getting-started-react-navigation)

In this example setup how can you pass data from ResultStack to LabStack

```
export const ResultStack = StackNavigator({
  Result: {
    screen: Result,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
     headerTintColor: "#FFF",
     headerLeft: (<Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)} />),
     headerRight: (<Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Lab', { someKey: SomeValue }) } />),
    }),
  ...
  }
})

export const LabStack = StackNavigator({
 Lab: { ... }
 ...
})

export const TabStack = TabNavigator({
 ResultStack: { ... }
 LabStack: { ... }
})

export const Root = StackNavigator({
  ...
  Main: {
    screen: TabStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: After trying to solve this issue for weeks I eventually resorted to using redux.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need redux for this. I managed to do it with the following. It it is almost identical to your code. Just added title on the buttons.

```
const ResultStack = StackNavigator({
  Result: { screen: Result,
    navigationOptions :({ navigation }) =>  ({
      title: 'Page 2 SettingsTab',
      headerTintColor: "#FFF",
      headerLeft: (<Button title='Back' onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)} />),
      headerRight: (<Button title='Back' onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Lab', { someKey: 'SomeValue' }) } />),
   }), 
  },
});
```

Then someKey is reached in lab by

```
console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.someKey)
```

If you would like to to pass the values as `navigation.state.params`. These params must be available at the screen you are navigating from otherwise these will be undefined in the next screen.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this is the correct method. Although it didn't work it helped me to realise that I cannot pass data to another stack.  After testing by passing state to different views I noticed it will only work in the same stack even though I can navigate to other stacks.